# Reference(s) describing various challenges of introducing artificial intelligence into medicine

Tags: research

I'm looking for reference(s) describing various challenges of introducing artificial intelligence algorithms into medical practice. Preferably, references should be scholarly and comprehensive.

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- http://qr.ae/TbckAz
- https://redd.it/6zxh14

Answer (score 2):

You can follow our most recent published work, titled as "Introduction of Human-Centric AI Assistant to Aid Radiologists for Multimodal Breast Image Classification" [3] and published in a top Human-Computer Interaction (HCI) journal. We also have similar works [1, 2] under the HCI topic that you might be interested.

Furthermore, you can look at several of my posts where I do some literature review:

- "[Applying New Paradigms in Human-Computer Interaction to Health Informatics](https://medium.com/oppr/applying-new-paradigms-in-human-computer-interaction-to-health-informatics-86d6a7046130)"
- "[Using CornerstoneJS and Orthanc to Support Deep Learning Projects](https://medium.com/oppr/using-cornerstonejs-and-orthanc-to-support-deep-learning-projects-c9675819c33a)"
- "[Medical Imaging Downloader for CornerstoneJS and Orthanc](https://medium.com/oppr/medical-imaging-downloader-for-cornerstonejs-and-orthanc-d08c3a508d9b)"

## References

[1] Francisco M. Calisto, Alfredo Ferreira, Jacinto C. Nascimento, and Daniel Gonçalves. 2017. Towards Touch-Based Medical Image Diagnosis Annotation. In Proceedings of the 2017 ACM International Conference on Interactive Surfaces and Spaces (ISS '17). Association for Computing Machinery, New York, NY, USA, 390–395. DOI: https://doi.org/10.1145/3132272.3134111

[2] Francisco Maria Calisto, Nuno Nunes, and Jacinto C. Nascimento. 2020. BreastScreening: On the Use of Multi-Modality in Medical Imaging Diagnosis. In Proceedings of the International Conference on Advanced Visual Interfaces (AVI '20). Association for Computing Machinery, New York, NY, USA, Article 49, 1–5. DOI: https://doi.org/10.1145/3399715.3399744

[3] Francisco Maria Calisto, Carlos Santiago, Nuno Nunes, Jacinto C. Nascimento, Introduction of human-centric AI assistant to aid radiologists for multimodal breast image classification, International Journal of Human-Computer Studies, Volume 150, 2021, 102607, ISSN 1071-5819, DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijhcs.2021.102607

Comment: Very cool, thanks for sharing!